# TSQL TOP Number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a script that pulls TOP 7 of "Category" by SUM(CallCount).

```
SELECT TOP (ISNULL(CAST(7 AS INT), 0)) 
    F.Category,
    CallCount = SUM(F.callcount)
FROM 
    #FINAL F
GROUP BY
    F.Category
ORDER BY
    SUM(F.CallCount) DESC
```

[image]

Total `CallCount` is 2,679,703, and I need to divide each total category call count by 2,679,703 to get the % that should total to 100%, but I just don't know how to incorporate the Total CallCount of 2,679,703 in the code below.

[image]

The TtlCount and CallCount overall total should match and CallCountPercent should total to 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to show a different way to sum numbers and eliminate group by. I am using over to partition the row set of  table and selecting a dummy value to get the sum.

```
SELECT TOP (ISNULL(cast(7 as int),0)) F.Category,
      SUM(F.callcount) OVER (PARTITION BY F.category ) as callcount,
      (SUM(F.callcount) OVER (PARTITION BY( SELECT 0))) as Totalcount
     ,CAST(1. * F.callcount/ SUM(F.callcount) OVER(PARTITION BY ( SELECT 0)) *100 AS DECIMAL(5,2)) as percentage
FROM #FINAL F
order by F.CallCount desc
```

This gives you better execution plans as well on larger dataset.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @developer the total percentage is not totaling to 100% in the above sample. I got it working for now. Since im using the Top X I need to put it first in a #temp table then do the division to get the % of Top X of records.  Thanks for replying :)

Comment: @Arsee, I would to have it round it up to get the total to be 100%. please see the changed script and output now.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide by a subquery which finds the total call count sum:

```
SELECT TOP ISNULL(cast(7 as int), 0) F.Category,
           SUM(F.callcount) AS CallCount,
           100 * SUM(F.callcount) /
               (SELECT SUM(callcount) FROM #FINAL) AS CallCountPercent
FROM #FINAL F
GROUP BY F.Category
ORDER BY SUM(F.CallCount) desc
```

Comment: Code worked but I have to place the result in a temp table then query of that temp table. since it is pulling top X of category.

Comment: @Arsee So are you looking for me to update something?

Comment: I'm good.. I just need to construct the one line code to incorporate just the total by using temp table for final result. thank you for you help. appreciate it. :)